# Why Adding Bootstrap misses my angular form elements?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an angular Project.

I have added Bootstrap.

In my component.html I have a form.

Adding bootstrap causes  my angular form elements design to be broken.

here is a sample markeup

```
<form [formGroup]="this.participantSearchService.searchParticipantForm"  (ngSubmit)="this.participantSearchService.onSubmit()">

    <div class="formsTitle">
        <span style="color:#fff; font-size: 15px">{{ this.appService.title}}</span>
    </div>
    <table class="label" width="100%">
        <colgroup class="label-td" width="130">
        </colgroup>
        <colgroup width="380">
        </colgroup>
        <colgroup class="label-td" width="130">
        </colgroup>
        <colgroup width="380">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>جهة المشارك </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select formControlName="participantLocation">
                        <option value="" >A</option>
                        <option value="1">B</option>
                        <option value="2">C</option>
                    </select>

                </td>
</form>
```

Any Idea ?

Here is a screen shot. 
[image]

Comment: Nobody can help you without seeing your markup.

Comment: @AdrianBrand it is just a from with elements

Comment: It's not a form, it seems to be a table. Why do you need a table here, are you displaying tabular data? If not, then remove the table alltogether and use bootstrap columns to align your formelements.